# Super product attributes configuration in Magento via Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

I've followed the instructions in Magmi's wiki but still can't import super attribute pricing info to my configurable product. I'm hoping someone can take a look at my setup and point out what I'm doing wrong.

Configurable product:

```
"sku","name","categories","configurable_attributes","type","description","short_description","tax_class_id","attribute_set","store","weight","is_in_stock","status","visibility","product_in_stock","price","super_attribute_pricing","image","small_image","thumbnail","qty"
"000592363","Speedo F.Banho Swimstar Leaderback Jr","TEXTIL\F.BANHO NATAÇAO","tamanhoecor","configurable",".",".","Taxable Goods","Default","admin","1","1","enabled","Catalog, Search","5","27.2358","Tamanho e cor::Rosa, 6A:0:0;Rosa, 8A:1:0","000592363.png","000592363_peq.png","000592363_peq.png","7"
```

Simple products:

```
"sku","name","tamanhoecor","qty","categories","configurable_attributes","description","short_description","tax_class_id","attribute_set","store","weight","visibility","price"
"000592363.39.29","Speedo F.Banho Swimstar Leaderback Jr Rosa 6A","(Cor) Rosa, (Tam.) 6A","2","TEXTIL\F.BANHO NATAÇAO","Default",".",".","Taxable Goods","tamanhoecor","admin","1","Not Visible Individually","27.2358"
"000592363.39.31","Speedo F.Banho Swimstar Leaderback Jr Rosa 8A","(Cor) Rosa, (Tam.) 8A","2","TEXTIL\F.BANHO NATAÇAO","Default",".",".","Taxable Goods","tamanhoecor","admin","1","Not Visible Individually","28.2358"
```

My attribute set is named tamanhoecor and includes an attribute with the same name.

attribute set: “tamanhoecor”

attribute code: “tamanhoecor”
attribute title “Tamanho e cor”

Assigned attribute "tamanhoecor" attribute to "Default" attribute set.

magento screenshot -> http://dl.dropbox.com/u/56372088/forums/superattpricing.PNG

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue, we have the same set up but using the 'Colour' attribute and our pricing information looks the same as shown in the screenshot...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out no commas are allowed in the attribute.
Just changed "(Cor) Rosa, (Tam.) 6A" to "(Cor) Rosa (Tam.) 6A" and it worked.